# Python Dataframes: how to remove certain characters and change datatypes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataset similar to

`id year    losses        revenue     expenses
2   2015    $400,000    $-            $230,000
1   2017    $-          $750,000      $12,000
3   2011    $-          $1,200,000    $750,000
1   2012    $150,000   $250,000     $120,000
2   2006    $120,000    $14,000   $3,000
4   2008    $-          $350,000      $120,000
5   2019    $5,000      $-            $-
4   2001    $12,000    $-             $7,500
4   2004    $50,000 $450,000      $10,000`

My desired result is to group by the `id` column and find the average of each column. Values of `$-` should simply be ignored.

`id losses      revenue     expenses
2   400,000     14,000      116,500
1   150,000     500,000     66,000
3   -          1,200,000    750,000
4   31,000     400,000      45,833
5   5,000         -            -`

I started by trying to remove the `$` from the `losses` column by

`df['losses'] = [x.lstrip('$') for x in df['losses']]`

But it doesn't seem to do anything. I do not receive an error when I run it, but the dollar signs still remain. I'm looking to remove `$` from the `losses` `revenue` and `expenses` columns. I'd then be converting them into integer datatypes so that I can group by `id` and find the averages of the columns by using

`df.groupby('id')['losses', 'revenue', expenses'].mean().reset_index()`

Comment: The dollar signs are removed for me, do you possibly have leading whitespace which will cause problems? `' $50,000'.lstrip('$')` won't get stripped.

Comment: I checked and from I can tell, it doesn't look there is any whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st we need to convert the accounting number to numeric here i use `replace`, then we `groupby`

```
df.replace({'[\$,]': '','-':np.nan},regex=True).astype(float).groupby('id').mean().drop('year',1)
       losses    revenue       expenses
id                                     
1.0  150000.0   500000.0   66000.000000
2.0  260000.0    14000.0  116500.000000
3.0       NaN  1200000.0  750000.000000
4.0   31000.0   400000.0   45833.333333
5.0    5000.0        NaN            NaN
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was going to post except I was dropping year first...

Comment: Thinking about it... maybe a slight tweak could be: `df.loc[:, 'losses':].replace({'[\$,]': '','-':np.nan},regex=True).astype(float).groupby(df['id']).mean()`... then the replace has less columns to operate on, the id remains integer and year doesn't need dropping but...

Comment: @JonClements yes you are right this will speed up the whole process

Comment: @JonClements I used your solution and it worked perfectly. Referring to the original example that I provided, what if I wanted to groupby both `id` and `year`? I am currently getting a key error when trying something like `...groupby(df['id', 'year'])...`. I have grouped by multiple columns before but this format seems to be a bit different. I'm unsure on how to do it in this case without adding at least a couple more lines of code.